# How to fetch specific data from Firestore and update it in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-firestore

I have to fetch my user from Firestore and then I want to update my image which is string. I am stuck at one place.

Here is my code:

```
FIRFirestore *defaultFirestore = [FIRFirestore firestore];
FIRCollectionReference *colRef = [defaultFirestore collectionWithPath:@"users"]; // to fetch my user profile 
[colRef queryWhereField:@"name" isEqualTo:currentUser.name];

[colRef getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
          NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
        } else {
          for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
              NSLog(@"%@", document.data); // my profile and after that I want to update the image
          // here I want to update the user image how can I do it ??

          }
        }
      }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 FIRFirestore *defaultFirestore = [FIRFirestore firestore];

    FIRCollectionReference *colRef = [defaultFirestore collectionWithPath:@"users"];

    FIRQuery *query = [colRef queryWhereField:@"name" isEqualTo:@"SIDDHANT Nigam"];

    [query getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {

            if (error != nil) {

              NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);

            } else {

               FIRDocumentSnapshot *document = snapshot.documents.firstObject;

               [document.reference updateData:@{

                        @"imageurl": @""

               }];
            }

          }];

}
```